# How to execute file created by my program?

Tags: go, exec, icalendar

I'm trying to execute *.ics* file that my program just created. Basically, my program is simple CLI calendar app, which generates .ics file. It would be nice if my program would execute this file and add it straight to OS calendar app, without unnecessary searching and executing through OS GUI.
I paste main function to better understanding.

```
func main() {

    serialized, name := cal()

    f, err := os.Create(name + ".ics")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    _, err2 := f.WriteString(serialized)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(name + ".ics")
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

As it's shown I tried with `exec.Command`, but it doesnt' work. I was even trying with additional prefixes like `./` or `~/`, but it as well didn't work.

**Error messages:**

`fork/exec ./Meeting.ics: permission denied`

`exec: "Meeting.ics": executable file not found in $PATH`

**So to sum it up - I want to skip the process where the user has to find a file and open it. I want to make it automatically as a part of my application.**

Here's my repository if it would help https://github.com/lenoopaleno/golang-calendar

I'm working on WSL 2, Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This is system dependent. You need to run a program to open the contents of the file. See  for example https://github.com/speedata/publisher/blob/750feb974ddb169f469d814fdf4975a7e99b7ac4/src/go/sp/sp/sp.go#L264 and the contents of the open program variable: https://github.com/speedata/publisher/blob/750feb974ddb169f469d814fdf4975a7e99b7ac4/src/go/sp/sp/sp.go#L161 - this opens the file just created (a PDF file in this case) - I don't put this an answer because I don't know how to do this on WSL 2.

Comment: on Mac OS, you can use the `open` program to automatically bring up the appropriate application for the file .  `open <path>`.  Not sure it will work for `.ics` files but it would be worth a try

Comment: For windows, try the `start` command which should work similarly (https://superuser.com/questions/38975/windows-equivalent-command-for-open-command-on-mac).

Answer (score 1):

Beside the comments above, you might have a problem in your code with the `defer f.Close()`

The defer runs when the function ends. Until that time your file might or might not be closed and accessible by a different process.
Second you will most likely have to set an execute flag on the a program to run under unix style operating systems.

Program adjustment:

```
func main() {

    serialized, name := cal()

    f, err := os.Create(name + ".ics")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _, err2 := f.WriteString(serialized)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }
    f.Sync()
    f.Close()
    exec.Command(`chmod +x `+name+".ics").Run() // This can be done prettier
    cmd := exec.Command(name + ".ics")
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, and even error is the same: `exec: "Meeting.ics": executable file not found in $PATH`

Comment: You will have the full path to your file.
$PATH is a shell parameter, and might not even be present when using exec.

Comment: I changed the path (I thought he will find executable in working directory, my bad), but idk if it's good - 
`exec.Command(chmod +x  + "Z:\\home\\jano\\GolandProjects\\golang-calendar\\src\\Meeting.ics").Run() // This can be done prettier
 
cmd := exec.Command(name + ".ics")
 
err = cmd.Run()`

Still doesn't work, and the error message is same. Path is copied from Windows explorer, but path provided in GoLand doesnt work as well.

Comment: Ah, windows.... That changes everything. The command provides is for unix

Comment: Yeah, but whole program works on WSL (like i mentioned in question)

Comment: you can't just add executable to a random file and expect that to work, even in unix.  That's a calendar file, not an executable.  You need to execute the calendar app.

Comment: You get me wrong - I'm using Ubuntu terminal, so it's not about windows command. The problem is about execution of *.ics * file. I tried a lot of possible solutions but none worked.

Comment: `Z:\\home\\jano\\G` etc is a windows style path definition. Unix looks like `/home/jano`
As for execution: It does have to be an executable file. You will have to use a program to load your .ics file with.